# Breadboards is this possible?

Tags: hardware, breadboard

Is it possible to customise a breadboard to suite a project?

Basically, I need to design a model of a "street" that has roads, and buildings on a breadboard that interacts with a Pi but making the wires as less visible as possible but I don't want to break it and it loses it's functionality.. Is this possible, or, could anyone recommend any alternatives?

P.S. there were no tags for this specifically

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure I know what you mean...

Comment: @Jivings Thank you for your reply. Basically, I want to make a model of a street, so it would have buildings, traffic lights etc using paper mesh etc.. But it will actually be on the breadboard which connects to the Pi.. Is this better? haha

Comment: I also added a `breadboard` tag for you.

Comment: Breadboards are only used for prototyping.I recommend something more stable if its going to be permanent. Etching a PCB would better if you don't want wires to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you can't buy a standard breadboard, or a few of them, and then set them up how you are asking.

Breadboards usually have jigsaw type connections so that you can clip them all together. You can then just connect up your electronics and build your model on top of it all.

Comment: Aha thank you for your reply :D!! That's great to know, I just didn't want to buy it and then it didn't work.. Basically, I just need to use LEDS for some traffic lights as well as some street lights (models i've made using a 3D printer) so was thinking about glueing them onto the board but without breaking it haha!

Comment: Should be fine, they are pretty simple pieces of kit.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like the geometry of standard breadboards and especially the connections within is likely to be a good fit for your project.

You might be able to use one of the smallest breadboard modules everywhere you need something.

Or you could buy just the terminal strips usually found on the outside, and not the "IC" modules that form the core of most breadboard setups.

But you might also want to look into other prototyping technologies, such as point to point wiring, pre-drilled generic PC boards, wire wrap, dead-bug construction, even prototype PC boards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply? Something like this? http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B007G4O5EU/ i get the idea, since I only need to control the models of the traffic lights so I can simply add the breadboards to where the traffic lights instead of the whole thing on a breadboard..

Comment: Yes, you should be able to find those little ones individually, or in a package of several. But after a few to test your design, you might as well make PC boards, or use the premade PC boards with the same layout as those.

Comment: I just need this to demonstrate how Speech can interact within the real-world (but using a model) so I don't think it needs to be on a PCB because it will just be shown once and probably never shown again haha! Thanks :)!